# Deserialize Html.Serialize intro ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have View Model with inner ViewModel Address propery.

```
public class CommonViewModel{

public AddressViewModel PreviouslyAddress { get; set; }

}
```

And Address:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class AddressViewModel 
    {
        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        public string Address2 { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string Prefix { get; set; }

        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

I want to serialize it, and get deseriliazed on POST.

I use:

```
@Html.Serialize("PreviouslyAddress", Model.PreviouslyAddress)
```

But in all examples they use Attribute `DeserializeAttribute` which can be implemented only in method parameters.

Example [enter link description here](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/03/06/persisting-model-state-in-asp-net-mvc-using-html-serialize.aspx)

EDITED

How can I do it without create custom bunding and send part of my model as parameter.

```
    [HttpPost]              
public ActionResult Register([DeserializeAttribute] AddressViewModel user, FormCollection userForm)
{
    TryUpdateModel(user, userForm.ToValueProvider());
```

For example, if it is possible I want something like this:

```
[HttpPost]              
public ActionResult Register(CommonViewModel model)
{
    TryUpdateModel(user, userForm.ToValueProvider());

 public class CommonViewModel{

        [DeserializeAttribute]
        public AddressViewModel PreviouslyAddress { get; set; }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `MvcSerializer` class to deserialize manually some string back into a model:

```
var serializer = new MvcSerializer();
var value = Request["previouslyAddress"]; // this is the contents of the hidden field
var address = (AddressViewModel)serializer.Deserialize(value, SerializationMode.Signed);
```

Comment: Just today, I saw some ASP.MVC questions. You have answered for it. I want to say thank you for your work with ASP.MVC. 

I can do it manually (I did :)), but I want to use ASP.NET defualt functional. But I see it doesnt`t exist :(

Comment: @IvanKorytin, what default functionality you want to use? You could also use the `[Deserialize]` attribute to decorate your action argument. It will then be automatically deserialized. Also don't forget that this is not ASP.NET MVC built-in functionality. It is part of the MVCContrib project, so I wonder what default functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I mean that I, for example, apply [Deserialize] attribute for propery, which I am going deserializy. Some think like that I called "Default".

Comment: I added some example, what I want to get. I have resolved this problem by custom binder and custom serializer for my hidden field. But I think that It`s not the best solutions.